# Are functions defined as global or extern by default in C

Tags: c, function, global, extern

This site is saying that functions are global by default in C - visit http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/what-are-static-functions-in-c/

And this one is saying that functions are extern by default in C - visit
http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/08/c-static-variables-functions/

So, are they global or extern by default?

Comment: they are both global and extern by default.  There is nothing about the nature of "global" and nature of "extern" that implies that the two should be mutually exclusive.

Comment: For many purposes, the terms global and extern as synonymous.  It might be arguable that extern means 'declared here, defined elsewhere' while global means 'defined here but accessible elsewhere'.